# Deinit not calling - Cannot find why something is retaining (code provided)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, first-responder, manual-retain-release

I have discovered that my UIViewcontroller is not calling `deinit()` under the following scenario.
I am using this code extension to make my life easier by adding tap gesture recognizers.

https://gist.github.com/saoudrizwan/548aa90be174320fbaa6b3e71f01f6ae

I've used this code in one of my VCs, which I've stripped down to the barest minimum amount of code:

and in `viewDidLoad()` I did this:

```
// When the user taps on a label, have its related textbox automatically get the caret so they can type
// Add tapping so when you tap on a label it makes the corresponding textbox first responder
lblSubject.addTapGestureRecognizer {
 self.txtSubject.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

It appears that the line:

```
self.txtSubject.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Is the problem - when I leave this line above in that closure, `deinit()` does not call in my VC.
When I take the above line out or replace it with something like `print("hello world")`
`deinit()` properly calls. txtSubject is     `@IBOutlet weak var txtSubject: UITextField!`

I am not entirely sure what to do here. I read that when you trigger `becomeFirstResponder()` it's important you call `resignFirstResponder()`, but even if I don't tap the label (so as to not give `becomeFirstResponder()` a chance to even call) I still cannot hit `deinit()`

Any ideas where I can look further?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
self.txtSubject.becomeFirstResponder()
```

To

```
[unowned self] in self.txtSubject.becomeFirstResponder()
```

`unowned` is often feared as dangerous, but there is no danger here. If `self` ceases to exist, there will be nothing to tap and the code will never run.

Comment: using [txtSubject] ended up not hitting deinit() and increasing memory. Using [unowned self] worked correctly and hit deinit()! thank you!

Comment: for every closure should I do unowned self in? For example:  if (self.userProfile != nil){
            if let cachedProfileImage = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).imageCache.image(withIdentifier: self.userProfile!.id.description)
            {
                self.imgAvatar.image = cachedProfileImage
            }
            else {
                UserService.getProfilePicture {
                    response in
                    self.imgAvatar.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill 
                //set stuff here, work with response to set image..
        }

Comment: None of those are closures.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic retain loop. The `self.` inside of the closure is there to remind you to think about this. I assume that `self` is retaining `lblSubject`, and (via a `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` associated key), `lblSubject` is retaining `self` because it's captured by this closure.

You don't really need `self` here, however. You just need `txtSubject`. So you can just capture that:

```
lblSubject.addTapGestureRecognizer { [txtSubject] in
    txtSubject.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Alternately, you can fall back to the giant `weak self` hammer (though this tends to be greatly over-used):

```
lblSubject.addTapGestureRecognizer { [weak self] in
    self?.txtSubject.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

The best way to explore this kind of bug is with Xcode's [Memory Graph](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-DontLinkElementID_1).

It is also a good idea to review the Swift docs on [Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: I didn't know you could do `[txtSubject] in` like that... have been using the weak self hammer for everything...

Comment: @aheze Be warned, this trick makes a copy. So it works this way only for classes. With structs the effect is different (but also useful): it captures the value now rather than at the time the closure runs.

Comment: @matt or aheze would you say it's better to use [weak self], [unowned self], or [txtSubject] or is it equivalent in my case